# Set colorbar resized beside each subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I'm writing my scientific article and I get a problem with my subplots.
Unfortunately, I get a colorbar too much higher than graphs.

I read this post : [Matplotlib: same height for colorbar as for plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26034777/matplotlib-same-height-for-colorbar-as-for-plot)

But I don't find a way to overwrite my script in order to resize my colorbar.

This is my script with my resize try :

```
fig3, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1,3)

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(16, 9)

convolution_locale = convolve(RotatePlot, Gaussian2DKernel(stddev=4)) # AFFICHAGE DE LA CARTE DE DENSITE CONVOLUEE POUR 2'
fig_smoothed_heatmap_locale = ax1.imshow(convolution_locale, interpolation='nearest')
ax1.set_title("Carte de densite convoluee 2'")
ax1.set_xlabel("X (arcmin)")
ax1.set_ylabel("Y (arcmin)")
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax1)
cax1 = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
fig3.colorbar(fig_smoothed_heatmap_locale,cax=cax1)
ax1.invert_yaxis()


convolution_grande = convolve(RotatePlot, Gaussian2DKernel(stddev=32)) # AFFICHAGE DE LA CARTE DE DENSITE CONVOLUEE POUR 8'
fig_smoothed_heatmap_grande = ax2.imshow(convolution_grande, interpolation='nearest')
ax2.set_title("Carte de densite convoluee 16'")
ax2.set_xlabel("X (arcmin)")
ax2.set_ylabel("Y (arcmin)")
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax1)
cax2 = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
fig3.colorbar(fig_smoothed_heatmap_grande,cax=cax2)
ax2.invert_yaxis()

convolution_diff = convolution_locale - convolution_grande # AFFICHAGE DE LA CARTE DE DENSITE CONVOLUEE 2' - 8'
fig_smoothed_tab_diff = ax3.imshow(convolution_diff, interpolation='nearest')
ax3.set_title("Carte 2' - Carte 16'")
ax3.set_xlabel("X (arcmin)")
ax3.set_ylabel("Y (arcmin)")
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax1)
cax3 = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
fig3.colorbar(fig_smoothed_tab_diff,cax=cax3)
ax3.invert_yaxis()

# Create space for labels between subplots
fig3.tight_layout()

fig3.savefig(outname3)
```

This is what I get :

[image]

Thank you if you have a solution ! :)

Comment: I see a colorbar exactly as high as each one of the subplots… what exactly is not working for you?

Comment: @gboffi Yes the size becomes good, but now I get my 3 colorbars on the same place instead beside each subplot :/

Comment: OK, so if you have a DIFFERENT PROBLEM either close this question and post a new one (I'd recommend this course of actions) or edit your question to reflect the new problem…

Comment: Afterthought after seeing Tom's answer: if Tom's answer works for the NEW problem, maybe it is better to update your question so that Q&A go together well.

Comment: @gboffi Ok I will update my question with the Tom's answer ;)
Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you create your 3 `divider` instances you always use `ax1`.

Change the second and third `dividers` to use `ax2` and `ax3`, e.g.:

```
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax2)
```

Here's your entire script, with the fixed lines:

```
fig3, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1,3)

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(16, 9)

convolution_locale = convolve(RotatePlot, Gaussian2DKernel(stddev=4)) # AFFICHAGE DE LA CARTE DE DENSITE CONVOLUEE POUR 2'
fig_smoothed_heatmap_locale = ax1.imshow(convolution_locale, interpolation='nearest')
ax1.set_title("Carte de densite convoluee 2'")
ax1.set_xlabel("X (arcmin)")
ax1.set_ylabel("Y (arcmin)")
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax1)
cax1 = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
fig3.colorbar(fig_smoothed_heatmap_locale,cax=cax1)
ax1.invert_yaxis()


convolution_grande = convolve(RotatePlot, Gaussian2DKernel(stddev=32)) # AFFICHAGE DE LA CARTE DE DENSITE CONVOLUEE POUR 8'
fig_smoothed_heatmap_grande = ax2.imshow(convolution_grande, interpolation='nearest')
ax2.set_title("Carte de densite convoluee 16'")
ax2.set_xlabel("X (arcmin)")
ax2.set_ylabel("Y (arcmin)")
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax2)          ### I changed this line
cax2 = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
fig3.colorbar(fig_smoothed_heatmap_grande,cax=cax2)
ax2.invert_yaxis()

convolution_diff = convolution_locale - convolution_grande # AFFICHAGE DE LA CARTE DE DENSITE CONVOLUEE 2' - 8'
fig_smoothed_tab_diff = ax3.imshow(convolution_diff, interpolation='nearest')
ax3.set_title("Carte 2' - Carte 16'")
ax3.set_xlabel("X (arcmin)")
ax3.set_ylabel("Y (arcmin)")
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax3)          ### I changed this line too
cax3 = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
fig3.colorbar(fig_smoothed_tab_diff,cax=cax3)
ax3.invert_yaxis()

# Create space for labels between subplots
fig3.tight_layout()

fig3.savefig(outname3)
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I didn't modify this line because my script makes 1200 lines and I didn't see this line.
Thank you to your answer :)